# Getting all screenshot display types and app preview types in App Store Connect API

Tags: app-store-connect-api

I see that one can get all app categories, but I don't see a way of getting all supported screenshot display types and app preview types. Is this possible and if not, is there some way of getting all supported types without having to download the [API specification?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi)